# cocos2d custom localization system for iphone games

Tags: objective-c, localization, cocos2d-iphone, localizable.strings

I'm using a [custom localization system](http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.com/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html?showComment=1333617868985#c5083869952868402149) for my game; in that tutorial he adds the label in a custom method but my text labels are added in init

Tutorial's example:

```
- (void) setHelloWorldLabel
{
    // create and initialize a Label
    CCLabel* label = [CCLabel labelWithString:AMLocalizedString(@"hello",@"Hello World") fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];

    // ask director the the window size
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    // position the label on the center of the screen
    label.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , size.height/2 );

    //Check if it's already been added to the layer.
    if ([self getChildByTag:50])
        [self removeChildByTag:50 cleanup:YES];

    // add the label as a child to this Layer
    [self addChild:label z:0 tag:50];
}
```

Setting a language

```
-(void) menuCallbackEN: (id) sender
{
    LocalizationSetLanguage(@"English");
    [self setHelloWorldLabel];
}
```

How to deal with multiple text labels?

Some code sample would help me :)

Comment: Do you mean to ask what to do when there are multipla labels with the tag `50` ?

Comment: @jonsibley: No, I mean when I have multiple text labels; different ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another method which could be called on init and on language change events.
This method should look like this:

```
- (void)initLocalizableLables
{
    // Remove old labels
    for (NSInteger i=[children_ count]-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        CCNode *c = [children_ objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([c isKindOfClass:[CCLabel class]])
        {
            [c removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
        }
    }

    // Add labels with localization    
    CCLabel* label = [CCLabel labelWithString:AMLocalizedString(@"hello",@"Hello World") fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
    ...
    [self addChild:label z:0 tag:50];
}

- (void)init
{
    ...
    [self initLocalizableLables]; // add localized labels
    ...
}

- (void)languageDidChange
{
    [self initLocalizableLables]; // remove old localized labels and add new
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But for my layer at some of them I have placed also some `CCMenuItem`s and `CCMenuItemsAndSprite` (label & background image). It gets its children but I receive: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'index out of range in objectAtIndex(14), index 15'`

Comment: Please post your pice of code, probably you need something like recursion for universal solution. You could also try to handle them manually by tag property or put all localazable objects into the mutable dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to give each label a different `tag`, create a dictionary using the tags as they key and the string as the value.  Then, iterate through each key (tag) in the dictionary and use it to retrieve each `CCLabel` (via `getChildByTag:`).  Lastly, call `setString:` on each `CCLabel` to update the newly localized string.